# PHP странное поведение кодировки

Tags: php, кодировка, notepad++

Есть 3 файла:
index.html - форма для ввода данных, либо просто для перехода на
index.php -  скрипт, который "что-то" делает, и передает результат в 
output.html - шаблон для вывода результата работы скрипта.

Суть проблемы в картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрипт выполняет учебное задание, а именно меняет местами каждую пару символов. С англ словами все работает, проблема в русских. Метод с решением:

```
function todo(){
            $src = "Почему один и тот жетекст отображается по-разному?";

            //$target = utf8_decode($src);
            $target = $src;
            $pos = 0;
            $tempstr = $target;
            //echo strlen(utf8_decode($target)) . "<br>";
            while(true){
                if($pos + 2 < strlen(utf8_decode($target))){
                    $a = substr($target, $pos, 1);
                    $b = substr($target, $pos + 1, 1);
                    $tempstr = substr_replace($tempstr, $a, $pos + 1, 1);
                    $tempstr = substr_replace($tempstr, $b, $pos, 1);
                    $pos += 2;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            return "initial: \t" . $target . "<br>" . "Result: \t" . $tempstr;         
        }
```

На всякий случай "шаблон":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><title><?=$title?></title>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="RELOAD" />
</form>
<font size="5" color="blue" face="Calibri"><pre>
<?php if($result): ?>
<span style="color:blue; font-weight:bold">Результат работы скрипта <?=$scriptName;?>:<br><?=$result;?></span>
<?php else: ?>
<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold">
Пусто..
<img src="megusto.png" alt="me gusto">
<?php endif; ?>
</span></font></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

В хроме стоит кодировка UTF-8. В Notepad++ стоит кодировка UTF-8 И отключена опция "авто-определение кодировки символов". Так же, как видно по комментам, я пытался использовать utf8_decode - бестолку. Судя по выводам echo через каждую строчку, у меня складывается ощущение что substr как-то коверкает $target

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

Я воспользовался советом, и решил задачу с помощью mb_strlen, mb_substr. Однако кое-что пришлось изменить:

```
function todo(){
            echo "<pre>";
            $target = "велосипедный костыль-костыльный велосипед";
            echo "target: \t" . $target . "<br>";
            $res = "";
            $pos = 0;
            while(true){
                if($pos > mb_strlen($target)) break;
                $a = mb_substr($target, $pos, 1);
                $b = mb_substr($target, $pos + 1, 1);
                $res .= $b . $a;
                $pos += 2;
            }
            echo "result: \t" . $res;
            echo "</pre>";
        }
```

Во первых оказалось, что для многобайтовых строк есть куча разных интересных функций, но нет функции аналога substr_replace. Поэтому мне пришлось составлять строку, а не заменять. Во вторых, для работы mbstring следует подключить модуль extension=php_mbstring.dll, который находится в файле **php.ini** - изначально он отключен (по крайней мере у меня). В любом случае, спасибо тем кто отклинулся, такая простая задача а так много узнал про PHP

Comment: Потому что в UTF-8 русские буквы кодируются 2мя байтами...

Comment: @Torin, смотрите в сторону функций работы с многобайтными строками http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для корректной работы с многобайтовыми строками следует использовать mb_strlen и mb_substr.

Comment: спасибо, оказалось познавательным

Comment: Обращайтесь, приятно иметь дело с благодарными людьми. Здесь не всегда так ))

Answer (score 1):

Вот где можно показать преимущество регулярных выражений над строковыми функциями:

```
<?php

$input = "Почему один и тот жетекст отображается по-разному?";
$output = preg_replace('%(.)(.)%us', '$2$1', $input);

var_dump($input, $output);
```

Результат:

```
string(92) "Почему один и тот жетекст отображается по-разному?"
string(92) "оПечумо ид н иот тежетск ттобоаражтеясп -оарнзмо?у"
```

О регулярных выражениях в php [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).
Функция [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: спасибо! это красивое решение, однако благодаря моему некрасивому я многое узнал про кодировки